# How do you extract a date from an image file and print it on to the image in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have to write a script in linux with the identify command to extract a date from an image file and add it to the image itself this has to be done for every file in the specified directory. Anyone who could help me? Thanks a lot! I'm now on to this:

```
for file in $picturemap 
do
identify -verbose $file > date.txt
date= date.txt grep | "date:create:"
done
```

its everything i know

Comment: you can refer this link http://superuser.com/questions/649033/add-timestamp-to-image-from-linux-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `imagemagick` package to `draw` on image files, `convert` them to other formats and lots of other stuff. There are huge amount of `switches` that can be useful, just reffer to the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php).

1. Install imagemagick

   ```
   sudo apt-get install imagemagick
   ```
2. Use `convert` command with `draw` switch.

Example:

```
convert test1.jpg  -weight 700  -pointsize 200 -draw "gravity north fill black text 0,100 'text' " test2.jpg
```

this will take `test1.jpg` annotate `text` with black color in your image and write it to `test.jpg`.